How to change the DDR( Double Data Rate SDRAM) frequency of Android under MTK platform
I have a question. It is necessary to call C/C++ through java's Java Native Interface to modify the Double Data Rate SDRAM (DDR) frequency of the android system under the MTK6877 platform, so that the DDR frequency is fixed to the required value, rather than automatically adjusting the change. I just started to develop android not long ago, I hope to get your help, thank you very much!
I searched the Internet for three days, only found the shell command to modify the cup frequency, did not find the desired method to modify the DDR frequency, currently in a state of no clue, what should I do now? Can you give me some advice?

When using abbreviations like DDR you should once use the long form so everybody knows what you are talking about, because DDR can be interpreted in multiple way like Dynamic Data Rate as using in RAM modules - but that doesn't make sense here.

I'm sorry. I'm so used to it at work that I didn't notice. The full name of DDR here is Double Data Rate SDRAM, the specific idea is to modify the Double Data Rate SDRAM frequency in Android system 9.0 and the chip is MTK6877, so that it is fixed ata certain value in the setting, rather than automatically changing.

Please edit your question and include your comment in it. Note that usually low level hardware settings can not be changed from Java level at least not from regular apps. May be your device has a special manufacturer specific API for changing such settings but regular Android has not to my knowledge.

You are right that java cannot modify the underlying hardware Settings. A Java native interface is required to invoke the C/ C ++ implementation. Can you explain the special manufacturer-specific api for changing these Settings? Or give some tips, instructions, such as instructions, web sites, etc. I will search for it. Thank you very much for your patient answer.

I just said that your device might have such an interface (theoretical possibility). How should I know if your device has such an interface and how to use it?

After some searching, I found the answer. The following three commands are given.
1、View supported OPP gears:adb shell "cat /sys/devices/platform/10012000.dvfsrc/helio-dvfsrc/dvfsrc_opp_table";
2、frequency locking：adb shell "echo i% > /sys/devices/platform/10012000.dvfsrc/helio-dvfsrc/dvfsrc_force_vcore_dvfs_opp";
3、View current frequency:adb shell "cat /sys/devices/platform/10012000.dvfsrc/helio-dvfsrc/dvfsrc_dump | grep -e uv -e khz -e FORCE -e CONTROL";
This needs to be done under root privileges.I tried the method and it worked.
